# sorting on field with an additional filter in Vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite

This might be a somewhat obscure use case.

As you can see below, I have the bar (`count`) overlaid. I want to sort the bars in the background (where `is_overview` set to 1), but currently, the filtering is set to all of `count`, which includes `is_overview` being set to 0.

I need the sort to be on a **filtered** field.

I went through the [sorting documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/sort.html) but I cannot figure out a way to support this use case. If you might have ideas, I would really appreciate the help!

[image]

[Editor code](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATZAgBOjQnh4qckALKNN6WGADiyJcl3o8yTWABqjWK3QSAXi7GYNwAZmBWeOihzqjIYGbocty6APrwLjQpAJ6pmt54+uysRspqGpCRmDigEBCQFH6sOthgANoadWC1XXXmSSnpmdQ5rZAAgtT68KxieKy68QBkYAByLgt+YABKOtwL8C3qvX3w+0p4rQCMAAzHJ1DeqdxUuhSMyADurYXNnXUAX3uXR6J36yTSGVcI102TGk2ms3mizAK3WyK2u0UByO-y6kDOrAu12BvUgTxeTneX1aoT8sGQeLAQKZwHBgyhWVh8N0eFgaighOJOAAHKpHrBnq9qd8cL9kCyTqCyYkIUNoaNTAAhHhibjUbKosAAGUYoXiAGV4B8lIdyg9BedLjgrtJSfiKdKPrKwPKmYremzVRzhpqoFrWLBGI5YPzxQSndcAMzxz1U70-XTNAMgpn1YOQ0Pc0wAYW4qFQRMYUOMNhWACl9rolH5vKh7Q8E0TnWA3XmJVL0zS5VnGScc3VlfiC+quXDS+XCCUnHWEi4BEF4HH+13hWArld3X0028MyO-uOj0GBoWNcWoABRTSsGtleNCntXABsqcllNPw6+qOE4QNeaqcjC86PkoTCOE40bUAKu49gATAAnL+g4AT68ogd07K3nOYwABLIH4LBIR+1woZh-4ypm2ZXjuM4QWGkDEawGBKMwHyrqa7BOFs4y8tuDrIdcACsR71Ce9HnmOvR4VOfQsUWUGQAAkkoz6wIUjBCSJRplkoPhxLoYAWumhyiZ2VE4AA7NJA50WeQEXopV4EbOkFjFpri6PkCAGBILbcu+iYurRXqAbhTFiapd7qca6CfEaAAKHASPAYBpdwWVwk54k4FJO6ya5fqXqyXmsfekBpYg2RRhkYgWdaDjWZREX7ncznRThwFxZ2CVEaYaWwNkSB5fqhorBa3DWlsADqKQANYdmCdlgBhpV-n1DEKV0SnVWpYxzQtLVWjadrhd2rQYb1Q79dm-wALoaAGkDtdw+Qwa0yqQAAHn9kChB8YiaGMw0+fGeDZIQyBjCkP1+Ehii8sDoPIODYxUQCE6QFBbKY9jphUTDcMI6YACOvgXMwQRUKjUTwGtOBKLMYj49whDoNasPA40YjNK0Nx0BJALvfckBiOg2ROK0HS5mCGC6KzUDsOgujrX0X0-YhNQ7mcepawbDr1MTEOmGVNJOfUsPw2MSjltGKO21ACB+JT+HODBXttJAADENw3EmD5flqSEB2hABiWpJiWIqQC98aaOW6DRgrdJiAy4ryi9eH4mINAOJbYDs2IYj9hLlVggyRfwKUJjdDu-jcOWf39nbFNjNG-mC9rYLsNGpeQB7Rc2WJhToCZMuuGMbSoPsDKp58ShtAAhMgVAXHQsCIGaeAANLINkydgJ8w-cJ8WCL5GyCsIQL1gAAfOfl-X7fDKL1Q68D2Srft1MJ8FAWNf5V0KnXZADdgb2y9pASscxGBIV1ghfkOB-ZAzPp9VAhh1JO0cJAauil-gTmUvAzWatIAay1keSAU8TKhBSO2dBRNGBzHljUUeWMoGNzGJA6BeNk5Mk+rab6CEO5iSNikCRZsQZgxHtbb4bs6Hd1ME7VALsxB-3xGPL2bIfbUD9oHUImgRSaCTPASOJj0DIC-OwJOKc04Z3QVnHOblkD52UUXQx2lWjl0rg6Ihh0SEaCEfURYigxCM04bo4GUiTaPG0sgeGSTiR4xAACIAA)

Comment: It sounds like you want to sort a non-filtered field on a filtered value. What do you expect to happen with the data rows that do not have a filtered value to sort on? Should they be at the beginning? The end? Not shown?

Comment: Hi Jake, that's a great point---for my specific use case, I would like the behavior to be at the end, but that's actually not all that important so long as it's consistent.

Comment: Also, there is another case, where there may be no filtered value (i.e. `"is_overview"` is always `false`)---in this case, I would like to defer to the `count` of other rows, where `is_overview` is `false`. However I understand that this is perhaps very niche and not supported by vega-lite. In general, it's a little hard to wrap my head around what is not possible in vega-lite (so far I've been very impressed!)

Comment: If you want that kind of complicated, custom logic, the best option would probably be to use a [calculate transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/calculate.html), which makes available all of the [vega expression syntax](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/), and define a new custom field on which to sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want custom sort behavior, often the best approach is to use a [calculate transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/calculate.html), which makes available all of the [vega expression syntax](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/), and define a new custom field on which to sort.

In your example, you could do something like this:

```
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "datum.is_overview ? datum.count : null", "as": "order"}
  ],
```

and then sort on the `order` property.

The result looks like this ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATZAgBOjQnh4qckALKNN6WGADiyJcl3o8yTWABqjWK3QSAXi7GYNwAZmBWeOihzqjIYGbocty6APrwLjQpAJ6pmt54+uysRspqGpCRmDigEBCQFH6sOthgANoadWC1XXXmSSnpmdQ5rZAAgtT68KxieKy68QBkYAByLgt+YABKOtwL8C3qvX3w+0p4rQCMAAzHJ1DeqdxUuhSMyADurYXNnXUAX3uXR6J36yTSGVcI102TGk2ms3mizAK3WyK2u0UByO-y6kDOrAu12BvUgTxeTneX1aoT8sGQeLAQKZwHBgyhWVh8N0eFgaighOJOAAHKpHrBnq9qd8cL9kCyTqCyYkIUNoaNTAAhHhibjUbKosAAGUYoXiAGV4B8lIdyg9BedLjgrtJSfiKdKPrKwPKmYremzVRzhpqoFrWLBGI5YPzxQSndcAMzxz1U70-XTNAMgpn1YOQ0Pc0wAYW4qFQRMYUOMNhWACl9rolH5vKh7Q8E0TnWA3XmJVL0zS5VnGScc3VlfiC+quXDS+XCCUnHWEi4BEF4HH+13hWArld3X0028MyO-uOj0GBoWNcWoABRTSsGtleNCntXABsqcllNPw6+qOE4QNeaqcjC86PkoTCOE40bUAKu49gATAAnL+g4AT68ogd07K3nOYwABLIH4LBIR+1woZh-4ypm2ZXjuM4QWGkDEawGBKMwHyrqa7BOFs4y8tuDrIdcACsR71Ce9HnmOvR4VOfQsUWUGQAAkkoz6wIUjBCSJRplkoPhxLoYAWumhyiZ2VE4AA7NJA50WeQEXopV4EbOkFjFpri6PkCAGBILbcu+iYurRXqAbhTFiapd7qca6CfEaAAKHASPAYBpdwWVwk54k4FJO6ya5fqXqyXmsfekBpYg2RRhkYgWdaDjWZREX7ncznRThwFxZ2CVEaYaWwNkSB5fqhorBa3DWlsADqKQANYdmCdlgBhpV-n1DEKV0SnVWpYxzQtLVWjadrhd2rQYb1Q79dm-wALoaAGkCFOgJmhCk7Y4B0IIEn4MxiJkYyRJxXC7Y9YAAPwRBsqB0B+YA4EosxiEh1hjCk2i6JAAIaC99yQO13D5DBrTKpAAAe1NMpAoQfGImhjMNPlHp92SEMguMBdGfjrX0ii8tTTMs2zph404hP-BOkBQWyzPIKzYxUfGeA83zpgAI6+BczBBFQSG6eg8BrejmMK9whDm8wSsNE0OtgDcdASUTEAfWD2SywD-zKZAGC6JbUDsOgBNc+TlOITUO5nHqBNxw69Qq2rphlTSTn1FrvNjEo5aC1j2dQAgfgu2yzgwS7bSQAAxDcNxJg+X5akhddoQAYlqSYliKkAk1o5boNGrRtHSYgMuK8ovXh+JiDQDhS2AGNiGI-aex5jMMgv8ClCY3Q7v43DlgzKdQLnLvkhcVJCyXkDsNGy+QGXC82WJX0mWDrhjG0qD7AyTQ3BPhKDaAAQmQFQC4dBYCIDNHgAA0sgbIg9PhP2AVgf+kZkCsEIC9MAAA+MAaDtIYKwQyf+VAwHCzBMfU+phPgoFVtQjehUd7ID3uLS+YxKxzEYEhaOCF+QAzpgPeMaBDDqQLo4OW455akkDsHUOD8I40IvlXWAv1dD-XaMrRgcw-b4XYXvYwYxjGXABACEmjNBFU2TrZKaSdD7nwlqrZ+mdvj324aYAuqAi5qPxK-CukAq7UBrvXUImgRSaCTPAdukT0DIC-OwMRQ8MCjwBhPKeblkCz3vgvMJ2lWir3Xg6Teh15bE1JosRQYgTY1Bfs1YJCcUhjCfsgXm2kHAWKJgCIAA)):

[image]